# how to add an image to a ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I have ListView and I want to add image to each item in the list. I've tried to many code but nothing work with me .

also I am using ListActivity and here is the code I am using,

```
public class DeviceScanActivity extends ListActivity {
    private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private boolean mScanning;
    private Handler mHandler;

    private ArrayList<String> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;


    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    // Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
    private static final String TAG = null;

    public static int RSSI;
    public static String NAME;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.scanning);

        mHandler = new Handler();


        // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.  Then you can
        // selectively disable BLE-related features.
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

        // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
        // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        this.getListView().setLongClickable(true);
        this.getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adpter, View v, int position, long id) {
               //Toast.makeText(DeviceScanActivity.this,"alaaaaaa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                openContextMenu(adpter);

                return false;
            }
        }); 
       registerForContextMenu(getListView());

 }





    final int CONTEXT_MENU_RENAME = 3;
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
    {

          menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_RENAME, Menu.NONE, "Rename");

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info= (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        Long id = getListView().getAdapter().getItemId(info.position);
        final int number_of_item_in_listview = Integer.valueOf(id.intValue());

        // final int context_menu_number = item.getItemId();
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Rename item");
        alert.setMessage("Enter new name for selected item");
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
            {
                String value = input.getText().toString();
                mDeviceList.set(number_of_item_in_listview, value);
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

         });


        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
            {

            }

        });

        alert.show();
        return(true);


        }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.details, menu);


        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        if (!mScanning) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(null);
        } else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(
                    R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
        }
        return true;


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_scan:
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
                scanLeDevice(true);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_stop:
                scanLeDevice(false);
                break;
        }



        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Ensures Bluetooth is enabled on the device.  If Bluetooth is not currently enabled,
        // fire an intent to display a dialog asking the user to grant permission to enable it.
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
        }

        // Initializes list view adapter.
        mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
        scanLeDevice(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // User chose not to enable Bluetooth.
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        scanLeDevice(false);
        mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        final BluetoothDevice device = mLeDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(position);
        if (device == null) return;


        Intent in = new Intent(this, FindIT.class);

        in.putExtra("name", NAME);


        in.putExtra("rssi", RSSI);


        startActivity(in);


        if (mScanning) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            mScanning = false;
        }


       // if (mLeDeviceListAdapter.isEmpty()) {

        //  MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound1);
            //mp.start();
            //Toast.makeText(DeviceScanActivity.this, R.string.none_found, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //}


    }

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.select_device);

                     if (mLeDeviceListAdapter.isEmpty()) {

                        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound1);
                    mp.start();
                        Toast.makeText(DeviceScanActivity.this, R.string.none_found, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                    mScanning = false;
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

                    invalidateOptionsMenu();


                }


            },  SCAN_PERIOD
            );

            mScanning = true;
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);





        }
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    } 





    // Adapter for holding devices found through scanning.
    private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


        private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
        private LayoutInflater mInflator;
        private final HashMap<BluetoothDevice, Integer> rssiMap = new HashMap<BluetoothDevice, Integer>();

        List<HashMap<String,String>> tag1 = 
                new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();


        public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
            super();
            mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

            mInflator = DeviceScanActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();



        }



        public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device , int rssi) {


            if(!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
                mLeDevices.add(device);
            }
            rssiMap.put(device, rssi);


           }


        public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
            return mLeDevices.get(position);
        }

        public void clear() {
            mLeDevices.clear();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mLeDevices.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return mLeDevices.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            ViewHolder viewHolder;

            // General ListView optimization code.
            if (view == null) {


                view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
               // viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
                viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
              //  viewHolder.deviceRssi = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rssi1);

                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
            final String deviceName = device.getName();
            if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0)
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
            else
            //  Planet p = planetList.get(position);

                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);

          //  viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());
          //  viewHolder.deviceRssi.setText(""+rssiMap.get(device)+" dBm");

            RSSI= rssiMap.get(device);
            NAME = device.getName();

            Toast.makeText(DeviceScanActivity.this,getCount() + " Device(s)" + "found" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound);
            mp.start();

            setTitle(R.string.connectedTags);

            return view;

        }
    }

    // Device scan callback.
    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device, rssi);
                    mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                }
            });
        }
    };

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView deviceName;

       // TextView deviceAddress;
       // TextView deviceRssi;
    }
}
```

can someone give me the right code to use ?

Comment: see http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/listview-with-images-and-text-using-simple-adapter-in-android/

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to add a `ImageView` to your custom row layout `list_item_device`.

```
<ImageView
  android:width="match_parent"
  android:height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/imageV" />
```

And, In `ViewHolder` class, add ImageView below TextView,

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView deviceName;
    ImageView img;
  }
```

In `getView` method,

```
 if (view == null) {

  view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
  viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
  viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
  viewHolder.img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageV);
  view.setTag(viewHolder);
```

Then, like how you set Text to `TextView`, do it for `ImageView` by,

```
viewHolder.img.setImageResource(resources should come here);
```

**EDIT :**

Sample code to display Text and Image in a listview - `list_item_device.xml`

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/device_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageV" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thank you ..it works fine ....but do you know how to let the text and image appear at the same row ??

Comment: In a RelativeLayout, add `Textview` along with `ImageView`. It will work & don't forget to upvote and accept if it's helpful :)

Comment: i am using relativeLayout

Comment: Check out my edit. You need to use graphical layout for to get neat layout.

Comment: Make sure the `id` mentioned in xml layout should be same when you do `findViewById(R.id.here)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like OutofMemory Errors use image loader. Download https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader and add this as a library to your application.
FIRST I WILL SHOW YOU HOW TO DO THIS WITH A LIST THAT GETS DATA FROM SQLITE
THIS IS YOUR LAYOUT

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:visibility="gone" />

   <TableRow
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="80dp" >

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/image"
           android:layout_width="75dp"
           android:layout_height="75dp"
           android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:scaleType="fitXY"
           android:textColor="#1464F4"
           android:textSize="16sp"
           android:textStyle="bold" />

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/name"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_weight=".2"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:hint="Cool Product"
         android:textColor="#1464F4"
         android:textSize="18sp"
         android:textStyle="bold" />

     <TableRow
         android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_weight=".1" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/description"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_weight=".1"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:hint="Very nice product"
         android:textColor="#1464F4"
         android:textSize="10sp" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
         android:text="$"
         android:textColor="#1464f4"
         android:textSize="24sp" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/p"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_weight=".1"
         android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
         android:hint="0.00"
         android:textColor="#1464F4"
         android:textSize="22sp"
         android:textStyle="bold" />

       </TableRow>
     </LinearLayout>
     </TableRow>
```

THIS IS YOU ADAPTER, THE IMPORTANT PART HERE IS THAT IMAGELOADER NEEDS A STRING

```
private static final class MyProductsAdapter extends CursorAdapter {


    MyProductsAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, flags);

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_stuff, parent, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id._id);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        TextView n = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView m = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
        TextView s = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.p);

        id.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        n.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
        m.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description")));
        s.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("p")));
        loader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
        loader.displayImage(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("image")), iv, op);
    }

    LayoutInflater mInflater;
}
```

THIS IS YOUR LIST

```
final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = controllerp.getReadableDatabase();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM Whatever where name IS NOT NULL ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE ASC";

    // rawQuery must not include a trailing ';'
    final Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);

    ((ListView) list).setAdapter(new MyProductsAdapter(context, cursor, 0));
```

IF YOU HAVE ANY QUESTIONS FEEL FREE TO ASK

Answer (score 0):

create custom list adapter and create xml layout file for list item.
In oreder if you want image and text to appear in same raw use LinearLayout
with orientation horizontal.
 Refer following tutorial if you still have query

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/